# i want to draw the gameboard with square grid in unity and i am a begineer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i want to draw a gameboard that has grids in it i have centerd gameboard width as 80%of total width and height as 60% of total height i have tried but still it is not compatible for all values of row and column please look into code and help me

```
private void SetupGrid()
{
    float height=Camera.main.orthographicSize*2f;
    float width=Camera.main.aspect*height;

    Debug.Log("height:"+height);
    Debug.Log("width:"+width);

    float possibleHeight=0.6f*height;
    float possibleWidth=0.8f*width;

    Debug.Log("possibleHeight:"+possibleHeight);
    Debug.Log("possibleWidth:"+possibleWidth);

    float eachcellWidth=possibleWidth/mWidth;
    float eachcellHeight=possibleHeight/mHeight;

    Debug.Log("eachcellWidth:"+eachcellWidth);
    Debug.Log("eachcellHeight:"+eachcellHeight);

    float cellCenterX=eachcellWidth/2;
    float cellCenterY=eachcellHeight/2;

    Debug.Log("cellCenterX:"+cellCenterX);
    Debug.Log("cellCenterY:"+cellCenterY);

    float offSetBetweenEachCell=eachcellWidth*0.15f;

    float startXpos=-(mWidth/2*eachcellWidth)+cellCenterX;
    float startYpos=-(mHeight/2*eachcellHeight)+cellCenterY;

    Debug.Log("start X position value:"+startXpos);
    Debug.Log("start Y position value:"+startYpos);

    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer=mTilePrefab.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    float actualSpriteWidth=spriteRenderer.sprite.bounds.size.x;
    float actualSpriteHeight=spriteRenderer.sprite.bounds.size.y;

    Debug.Log("Actual Sprite width:"+actualSpriteWidth);
    Debug.Log("Actual Sprite Height:"+actualSpriteHeight);

    float finalCellWidth=eachcellWidth-offSetBetweenEachCell;
    float finalCellHeight=eachcellHeight-offSetBetweenEachCell;

    Vector3 eachCellScaleUnit=new Vector3(finalCellWidth/actualSpriteWidth,finalCellHeight/actualSpriteHeight);

    Vector3 referenceVector=Vector3.one;
    GameObject cell=null;
    for(int i=0;i<mWidth;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<mHeight;j++)
        {
            float posX=startXpos+(j*eachcellWidth);
            float posY=startYpos+(i*eachcellHeight);

            referenceVector.x=posX;
            referenceVector.y=posY;

            cell=Instantiate(mTilePrefab,referenceVector,Quaternion.identity);
            cell.transform.localScale=eachCellScaleUnit;
        }
    }
}
```

but it is not square when i scale it according to row and column.
[image: Please refer the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm... I'm not sure what is your desired behaviour, but why are you expecting each grid cell to be square? Even `Debug.Log` says that `eachcellWidth` is `1.125` and `eachcellHeight` is `1.5`. You are scaling twice, once from `eachcell` values, and once from `actualSprite` values, so it's hard to figure out which value you want to scale to.

If what you want is making grid, you don't have to make it in hard way. Unity already supports constructing grid. Try reading [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Grid.html) and utilize it.

Comment: can u send me any tutorial how to use exactly the inbuilt grid in unity i am a begineer so help is appreciated